# Php cron job (wp-cron) not working

Tags: php, wp-cron, cron

I try to create a php cron job with help of the WP Control plugin. The purpose is to delete all files in the uploads directory for the current year and month.

I use this code:

```
$files = glob('./wp-content/uploads/' . date('Y') . '/' . date ('m') . '/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
chown ($files, 666); //set the permissions
if(is_file($file)){
  unlink($file); // delete file
}
```

It is not working.
When I set the first line of code:

```
$files = glob('./wp-content/uploads/' . date('Y') . '/' . date ('m') . '/*'); // get all file names
```

to

```
$files = glob('./wp-content/uploads/2019/01/*'); // get all file names`
```

it works.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that this line was the only change and did you checked what the date function returns? As far as i can see, the two lines should do the same, assuming that the date settings of the server are set correct and we are in January 2019.

Comment: Yeah, nothing else is changed. I did put this first line of code in a plugin file and used print_r to see the contents and it is listed fine. All files are present. It only will not work in a php cron job for whatever reason.

Comment: BTW if you know a better aproach to delete the uploaded images once an hour I welcome you to share it with me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213108/php-date-and-strtotime-return-wrong-months-on-cron  I'm guessing it's something similar to this